# In Paypal - Collect payment from customer & distribute the payment between two other Users (With PHP)

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal in my website and want customer must stay on same page during the payment process.

1. Customer pay using "**Credit card details**" on web page.
2. Customer **must remain on same page** (Don't leave the current page).
3. website will c**harge the money from customer account** and **immediate distribute the money to other two person**(A & B )
   A & B have their valid Paypal email address.

Now, My Questions is:

**Questions 1: In this, How many transaction will happen?**
**Questions 2: What payment method need to use to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

To collect the payment on your website, paypal account must be **"Paypal Pro"**

**Answer on Question 1:**
**Two Transaction**.
When you charge payment from Credit card, first money  will transfer to the merchant account.
from merchant account, you can transfer to another two Person.

**Answer on Question 2:**
Payment Method: **DoDirectPayment**
**Description**: to get the payment from customer without leaving the website.

Payment Method: **MassPayment**
**Description**: To distribute the payment between two or more person(Both must have paypal account).

**Useful link to understand more**.
http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2014/07/Paypal-Sandbox-doDirectpayment-Authorization-Capture-and-Masspayment-Code-Snippets.html